# Cannot get packages from official repository for eoan

Tags: apt, package-management

Today i noticed the very strange thing. Running `sudo apt update` tells me such terrible words:

```
$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease                  
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80] 
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Reading package lists... Done         
E: The repository «http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release» does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
E: The repository «http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release» does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
E: The repository «http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release» does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

Does it mean that official repository for Ubuntu eoan aren't supported more?

Comment: *Does it mean that official repository for Ubuntu eoan aren't supported more?*: Yes. 19.10 reached its end of life in July 2020.

Comment: @Kufly yes, it does, thanks a lot

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: The EOL occurred long ago, the repositories are *moved* after EOL has occurred (can be as soon as the next day, but it'll vary on which mirror as mirrors just *drop* EOL releases **after** EOL was reached). See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes or the next release notes (20.04) for upgrade instructions  but remember 19.10 means 2019-October release which had 9 months of supported life.. so calculated EOL is easy if you know 19.10 (2019-October)..

Comment: Use an LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months as is required for non-LTS releases.  Hopefully your machine is offline, if it's isn't you need to watch your messages closer as the *move* from *archives* to *old-releases* wasn't done recently.